# How to get label value of an object stored inside instance of fl.data.Dataprovider

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is a simple code. How can i get the value **without using the method "getItemAt()".**

```
import fl.controls.List ; 
import fl.data.DataProvider ;
import flash.utils.describeType;

var a_Lst:List  ; 
a_Lst.addItem({label:"a"});
a_Lst.addItem({label:"b"});


trace(a_Lst.dataProvider) //OUTPUT: DataProvider [[object Object] , [object Object]]


trace(a_Lst.dataProvider.getItemAt(0)); //<< GET THE VALUE "a"

trace(a_Lst.dataProvider[0]); //<< DON'T GET THE VALUE

for ( var a:String in a_Lst.dataProvider )
{
    trace( a) ;//  << DON'T GET ANY VALUE
}

for each ( var b:String in a_Lst.dataProvider )
{ 
    trace( b) ;// << DON'T GET ANY VALUE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
function show(list : List):void
{
    for (var i : uint = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        trace(list.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).label);
    }
}
```